# Applying a function to a recursively built list within the definition of the recursive function in haskell

Tags: haskell

This isn't a great example, but easy enough to get across what I'm asking.  Say I want to rebuild a list recursively and then apply the sort function to it after the list has been built.  Here's one implementation that gets the right answer, but not the way I'd like.

```
import Data.List
rebuild_and_sort :: [Int] -> [Int]
rebuild_and_sort [] = []
rebuild_and_sort (b:bs) = sort (b:rebuild_and_sort bs)
```

The problem is that sort would be called for every element in the argument list.  Is there some way to make it so that sort would only be called once after the list has been fully reconstructed without changing the arguments needed?

Comment: Why do you want to rebuild the list?

Comment: It was just an example to illustrate what I was asking for, it was the first thing that came to my head.

Comment: Does rebuilding a list seem fundamental to the problem you are working on though? I ask because the compiler often just eliminates any "rebuilding" of a structure like a list and just uses the original list instead of building a new one. It can do this because of immutability. So, you would probably have to find a way to trick the optimizer to get it to rebuild a list. Also, because of immutability, there really isn't a reason to ever rebuild a list in the first place so you might have some misconceptions about how you are approaching the implementation of the solution to your problem.

Comment: No, there's no rebuilding.  To be specific, I'm working on a school assignment involving simple  non deterministic finite state machines where most of the stuff is supposed to be defined recursively.  Some of the results have duplicates which don't provide any value and so need to be removed with nub from Data.List.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

delegate the recursion to the worker function and call sort at the top level

```
import Data.List(sort)

rbsort :: [Int] -> [Int]
rbsort = sort . go
     where go [] = []
           go (x:xs) = x: go xs  -- here you should be doing something useful
```